# KEYBINDING IN VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to switch quickly between explorer, coding field and command line without mouse. Thank for your attention

Comment: ctrl + ` key binding to toggle between terminal and editor

Comment: Yes. But how I can go back editor?

Comment: I said It is used to toggle between two do it again and you will be back in editor

Comment: I did it. Tks. How about code explorer?

Comment: yoi can use ctrl+B twice to to focus tree view

Answer (score 0):

**ctrl + `** key binding to toggle between terminal and editor